# Which number is omitted under the log in O(log n)?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

In O(log n),which base ,"2" or "10" is omitted? The way time complexity of log n bases on dividing a sequence ,so it should be 2. Usually, base 10 is omitted in log.

Comment: There was a [great question about this on cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109607/2131) a while back.

Answer (score 1):

This notation shows how the running time of an algorithm grows with respect to the size of N. It makes no difference what base its referring to. Just like it makes no difference if its O(n) or O(k*n) (being k a real constant).

Clarifying:

> A log in any given base X can be written as follows:
>
> log<sub>x</sub>(n)= <sup>log<sub>10</sub>(n)</sup> ⁄ <sub>log<sub>10</sub>(x)</sub>
>
> Let k=log<sub>10</sub>(x), so we have:
>
> log<sub>x</sub>(n)= (1 ⁄ k) × log<sub>10</sub>(n)
>
> Which is also a function of complexity log(n)

My suggestion to visualize this property easier is to think that multiplying a function by a constant make its graph  stretch (or shrink) vertically, which does not alter the shape of the curve itself. And the shape is what this notation is about.

From Wikipedia:

> [Similarly, logs with different constant bases are equivalent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties)

Comment: This answer is correct but a little hard to follow. Consider emphasizing that it does not matter what the base of the logarithm is as far as asymptotic notation is concerned because the logarithms in different bases differ by only a constant multiplicative factor.